# What causes a negative event timeout error to occur?

Tags: events, timeout, anylogic

I am getting an error in my model (shown below) saying an event is being scheduled in the past. I have run into this error before in other models, but I don't know why or how it occurs. Root.arrival is not the name of anything in my model, so it seems to be something internal to the AnyLogic engine. Unfortunately the stack trace doesn't give me any info about where this happens in my model, so I don't know how to diagnose the origin. Does anyone know generally why/when/how a negative timeout may occur? Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.arrival: Trying to schedule an event in the past. Negative timeout: -0.07519763751588471
   at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.EventOriginator.d(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.EventTimeout.restartTo(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.jk$d.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.jk.addMovingAgent(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.g.d(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.g.d(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.g.d(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.g.d(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.be.d(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.be.moveToInTime(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.be.moveToInTime(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.be.moveTo(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.ExtAgentWithSpatialMetricsDelegate.moveTo(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.MoveTo.c(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.MoveTo.d(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.MoveTo.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.MoveTo.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.MoveTo$1.onEnter(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay$9.onEnter(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.receiveImmediately(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.PlainTransfer$1.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.PlainTransfer$1.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.a(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.action(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal$a.execute(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler$l.execute(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.d(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.runFast(Unknown Source)
   at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.runFast(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things can cause it. In your case, it seems linked to a `MoveTo` block so you likely set the agent speed to a negative value.

Or maybe you defined it by "Trip time" and set that to a negative value:
[image]

In any case, it is worth learning to isolate such problems first. Use traceln commands to nudge yourself closer to the issue. Remove blocks, ...

Most of all: keep a history of your model dev so you can always revert to a version that does not trigger this. And then you have your root cause

Comment: All of the agent movedments in the moveTo blocks in my model are defined by Distance/Speed, and the only 2 agent types that flow through the blocks have nonzero positive speeds, so I don't know how they could have negative trip times.. I'll try putting tracelns everywhere and see if that reveals anything. Thanks - love your anylogic vids on youtube btw.